# Positioning Facebook comment widget

Tags: html, css, facebook

I need to add Facebook OpenGraph "like" buttons to an existing site that was not designed with this feature in mind. The problem is that the LIKE buttons fit in OK, but the comment widget is larger than its container, which is of a fixed size. Because all of the FB code happens in an Iframe, what are my options to control where it appears on my page?

[image]

Comment: But you can change the height and width of iframe?

Comment: I miss the point. How will this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't integrated this particular FB like functionality but I have used others like the fan box. There's usually some inline CSS included in the `<iframe>` that you can tweak.

Could you post the HTML & CSS that is being used?

Comment: Since the Iframe is coming from a different domain, the Same Origin Policy prevents my page from manipulating the CSS in the Iframe.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a simple case of embedding generated code like: <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: <fb:like 
  href='....' 
  layout='box_count' 
  width='425' 
  action='recommend' 
  font='lucida grande' 
  colorscheme='dark'>
 </fb:like>

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried adjusting the width from 425 to something smaller or is it still an issue? Looking at the SDK you might be able to draw the canvas to something that fits with FB.Canvas.setSize.

Comment: It seems the comment dialog is a fixed size, regardless of settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a width argument to configure how wide the generated iframe. You can also pass the URL to a css file to restyle the contents of the widget.

```
<fb:comments xid="neato" width="200" css="http://a.com/stylesheet.css"></fb:comments>
```